Android Java bluetooth doesn't read all bytes
I need to send and read some bytes from Bluetooth, like serial port.
I use next code to connect device:
  UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;


            try {
                tmp = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("chromium", "Socket's create() method failed", e);
            }

            mmSocket = tmp;



            try {
                mmSocket.connect();

               

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                   bluetoothOutStream = Globals.mmSocket.getOutputStream();
                   bluetoothInputStream = Globals.mmSocket.getInputStream();

and for send - get:
byte [] test = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03};

bluetoothService.write(test);

int bytesAvailable = 0;
            byte [] fullAnsw = new byte [1024];
            int numBytes = 0;

   bytesAvailable = Globals.bluetoothInputStream.available();
                if(bytesAvailable > 0) {

                    Log.d("TEST", "bytesAvailable: " + bytesAvailable);

                    numBytes = bluetoothInputStream.read (fullAnsw, 0, 1024);

                    Log.d("TEST", "numBytes: " + numBytes);

                }


as result, I get part of byte (196 length). And in the next write-read iteration I get part of bytes from previous packet. As I understand: it doesn't have time to read all bytes data. Please help, how to set any timeout or time to read all data?

There is no guarantee that read() fills the buffer or reads as many bytes as you specify. You have to loop. NB Code that depends on the success of code in a prior try block should be inside that try block. Don't write code like this.

But how to know, when the read is finish?
